# Enable/Disable a EventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I'm building a Chess game on JS, and every pieces of the board are "clickable", I added an `EventListener('click')` on them, I also added an `EventListener('click')` after that to select where should the piece go.

But I need to know if there's any kind of *interrupter* related to a `EventListener`, in order to switch between an enabling an `EventListener` and disabling it. For example, when an certain variable is true I'd only have white pieces clickable and black ones otherwise.

Comment: Why not just check the value of that variable, in an `if` statement for example, inside the one event handler?

Comment: But how would I **re-switch** to an active EventListener? Because I may have to switch between "Only White pieces can be clicked" and "Only black ones can be clicked" "Only white pieces can be clicked" , .... and that more than 50 times maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question. I meant exactly as in @CertainPerformance's answer - have a *single* event listener and just check the value of the variable inside that in deciding whether to execute the rest of the function or not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of considering how to enable or disable listeners individually, I think it would be easier to have all clicks go through the *same* listener, and have that listener first check the board state to see whether a click on that location is permitted. If not, return and don't do anything. If so, continue.

For example, you could have something like:

```
const board = [
  [ // row 1
    { // square 1A
      piece: 'rook',
      owner: 'white',
    }
    // ...
```

Then, inside the listener, navigate to the clicked square in the `board`, and check whether the `owner` corresponds to the current player or not.

```
// inside listener:
// you will need to implement logic to get the row and column
// from a clicked button
const clickedSquare = board[i][j];
if (clickedSquare.owner !== currentPlayer) {
  return;
}
// rest of function
```

When a turn ends, just toggle `currentPlayer` from `'black'` to `'white'` or back again.